# O que é Mineração de Dados?

Tags: terminologia

Bom, o título diz tudo:

> O que é Mineração de Dados?

Comment: Esse termo é visto mais com com banco de dados e BI.

Comment: Bem lembrado @rray, pode ser [isso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mining), ou [isso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitcoin_network), acho que se confundiu no termo, o primeiro é ontopic, o segundo offtopic

Comment: @rray atualizei a pergunta

Comment: @MarceloBoni atualizei a pergunta

Comment: Talvez isto seja o começo de uma resposta: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms174949(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: [dilmacoin.org](http://www.dilmacoin.org/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Mineração de dados ou do inglês *Data Mining***

Desde que a informação passou a ser tão importante para a tomada de decisão os dados passaram a ser armazenados em grandes escalas. E com o volume de dados armazenados crescendo diariamente, começou a aparecer o questionamento. O que fazer com tantos dados armazenados? As técnicas tradicionais de exploração de dados não são mais adequadas para tratar a grande maioria dos repositórios. Com a finalidade de responder a esta questão, foi proposta, no final da década de 80, a Mineração de
Dados, do inglês Data Mining.

A Mineração de Dados é uma das tecnologias mais promissoras da atualidade. Um dos fatores deste sucesso é o fato de dezenas, e muitas vezes centenas de milhões de reais serem gastos pelas companhias na coleta dos dados e, no entanto, nenhuma informação útil é identificada. Em seu trabalho, Han (2006) em seu [livro](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=pQws07tdpjoC&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR#v=onepage&q&f=false) refere-se a essa situação como "rico em dados, pobre em informação". Além da iniciativa privada, o setor público e o terceiro setor (ONGt’s) também podem se beneficiar com a Mineração de Dados.

Mineração de dados não é apenas usado pelo Bitcoin, mas Segundo Witten e Bramer podem ser utilizados em algumas das áreas de forma satisfatória, como:

- Retenção de clientes: identificação de perfis para determinados
  produtos, venda cruzada;
- Bancos: identificar padrões para auxiliar no gerenciamento de
  relacionamento com o cliente;
- Cartão de Crédito: identificar segmentos de mercado, identificar
  padrões de rotatividade;
- Cobrança: detecção de fraudes;
- Telemarketing: acesso facilitado aos dados do cliente;
- Medicina: indicação de diagnósticos mais precisos;
- Segurança: na detecção de atividades terroristas e criminais;
- Tomada de Decisão: filtrar as informações relevantes, fornecer
  indicadores de probabilidade.
- Um supermercado melhore a disposição de seus produtos nas
  prateleiras, através do padrão de consumo de seus clientes;

**Mas mineração de dados funciona na prática?**

A mineração de dados é utilizado em grandes quantidades de dados e usa análises matemática para derivar anomalias, padrões e correlações, captando apenas o que é relevante, através de uma educação prévia da ferramenta. As empresas utilizam esta tecnologia para suportar a tomada de decisões e proporcionar vantagens estratégicas. Usando uma ampla variedade de técnicas, você pode utilizar estas informações para aumentar as receitas, reduzir custos, melhorar o relacionamento com os clientes, reduzir riscos e entre outros.

O mais importante para qualquer projeto que decida usar a mineração de dados é definir claramente qual será o problema solucionado.

Segundo o site do [***SAS Institute***](https://www.sas.com/pt_br/insights/analytics/mineracao-de-dados.html#)

> Mineração de dados é definido como uma disciplina combinada,
>   representa uma variedade de métodos ou técnicas utilizadas em
>   diferentes capacidades analíticas que abordam uma gama de necessidades
>   organizacionais, respondem diferentes tipos de perguntas e usam
>   diferentes níveis de regras para se chegar a uma decisão.

E ainda definem várias tipo de modelagem, como: Modelagem descritiva, Modelagem preditiva e Modelagem prescritiva.

Um dos padrões mais difundidos para se trabalhar com mineração de dados é o CRISP-DM (*Cross-Industry Standard Processo of Data Mining*), devido à vasta literatura disponível e por atualmente ser considerado o padrão de maior aceitação, segundo HAN (2006).

Como afirma Olson et al. (2008) em seu [livro](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=2vb-LZEn8uUC&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false), o processo CRISP-DM consiste de seis fases organizadas de maneira cíclica, conforme mostra a figura abaixo. Além disto, apesar de ser composto por fases, o fluxo não é unidirecional, podendo ir e voltar entre as fases.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As fases do processo CRISP-DM, são:

1. **Entendimento dos Negócios:** Nessa etapa, o foco é entender qual o
   objetivo que se deseja atingir com a mineração de dados. O
   entendimento do negócio irá ajudar nas próximas etapas.
2. **Entendimento dos Dados:** As fontes fornecedoras dos dados podem vir
   de diversos locais e possuírem diversos formatos. Segundo Olson et
   al, após definir os objetivos, é necessário conhecer os dados
   visando: Descrever de forma clara o problema; Identificar os dados
   relevantes para o problema em questão; Certificar-se de que as
   variáveis relevantes para o projeto não são interdependentes.
   Normalmente as técnicas de agrupamento e de exploração visual também
   são utilizadas nesta etapa.
3. **Preparação dos Dados:** Devido às diversas origens possíveis, é comum que os dados não estejam preparados para que os métodos de Mineração de Dados sejam aplicados diretamente. Dependendo da qualidade desses dados, algumas ações podem ser necessárias. Este processo de limpeza dos dados geralmente envolve filtrar, combinar e preencher valores vazios.
4. **Modelagem:** É nesta fase que as técnicas (algoritmos) de mineração serão aplicadas. A escolha da(s) técnica(s) depende dos objetivos desejados.
   Mineração de Dados: Conceitos, Tarefas, Métodos e Ferramentas 5
5. **Avaliação:** Considerada uma fase crítica do processo de mineração, nesta etapa é necessária a participação de especialistas nos dados, conhecedores do negócio e tomadores de decisão. Diversas ferramentas gráficas são utilizadas para a visualização e análise dos resultados (modelos). Testes e validações, visando obter a confiabilidade nos modelos, devem ser executados (*cross validation, suplied test set, use training set, percentage split*) e indicadores para auxiliar a análise dos resultados precisam ser obtidos (matriz de confusão, índice de correção
   e incorreção de instâncias mineradas, estatística kappa, erro médio absoluto, erro relativo médio, precisão, F-measure, dentre outros).
6. **Distribuição:** Após executado o modelo com os dados reais e completos é necessário que os envolvidos conheçam os resultados.

> Obs.: Resposta baseada nos livros citados. Todos o conhecimento
>   repassados tem como base as afirmações e conhecimento dos altores
>   sobre tema