# O que é Ciência de Dados?

Tags: terminologia, aprendizagem-de-máquina, big-data

A matriz do Stack Overflow possui um site chamado [Data Science SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/). Eu, que sou um membro ativo da tag [R](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r), percebo que há poucas discussões a respeito deste assunto em outros lugares da versão brasileira do Stack Overflow. Me espanta que esta falta de assunto principalmente na tag [python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), [que algumas pesquisas indicam como sendo a linguagem mais popular para trabalhar com este assunto](https://businessoverbroadway.com/2019/01/13/programming-languages-most-used-and-recommended-by-data-scientists/).

Isto posto, tenho as seguintes perguntas para fazer:

- O que é Ciência de Dados?
- No que ela se difere da Estatística?
- Ciência de Dados, Mineração de Dados, Inteligência Artificial, Big Data e Aprendizagem de Máquina são todos sinônimos entre si ou há diferenças entre estes termos?
- Além de estatística, matemática e computação, quais são as outras competências que um cientista de dados deve possuir?

Criei este tópico inspirado pela pergunta [O que é Mineração de Dados ?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/227527/o-que-%C3%A9-minera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-dados), daqui mesmo do Stack Overflow PT.

Comment: Não entendi qual é a relação de Python e R com a pergunta, visto que ela parece meramente conceitual

Comment: O teu ponto é perfeitamente válido. Coloquei-a nestas tags para chamar mais a atenção de um provável público-alvo para ela.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X3paOmcrTjQ eu assisti esse video e consegui um geral rapidamente

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> O que é Ciência de Dados?

A ciência de dados combina a aplicação de assuntos como ciência da computação, engenharia de software, matemática, estatística, programação, economia e gerenciamento de negócios. Ela se baseia na coleta, preparação, análise, gerenciamento, visualização e armazenamento de grandes volumes de informações, onde em termos simples, pode ser entendida como tendo fortes conexões com bancos de dados, incluindo big data.

> No que ela se difere da Estatística?

A ciência de dados combina campos multidisciplinares e computação para interpretar dados para a tomada de decisões, enquanto as estatísticas se referem à análise matemática que usa modelos quantificados para representar um dado conjunto de dados.

A ciência de dados é mais orientada para o campo do big data, que procura fornecer informações de percepção a partir de grandes volumes de dados complexos. Por outro lado, as estatísticas fornecem a metodologia para coletar, analisar e tirar conclusões dos dados.

A ciência de dados utiliza ferramentas, técnicas e princípios para filtrar e categorizar grandes volumes de dados em conjuntos ou modelos de dados apropriados. Isso é contrário à estatística que se limita a ferramentas como análise de frequência, média, mediana, análise de variância , correlação e regressão, e assim por diante, para citar algumas.
A ciência de dados investigará e inspecionará os dados para deduzir a inferência factual, quantitativa e estatística. Isso se opõe à estatística que enfoca a análise usando técnicas padrão envolvendo fórmulas e métodos matemáticos.

> Além de estatística, matemática e computação, quais são as outras
>   competências que um cientista de dados deve possuir?

Um cientista de dados deve ter conjuntos de habilidades para analisar e simplificar problemas usando conjuntos de dados complexos para descobrir informações.

Algumas abordagens que o cientista de dados deve conhecer:

- Aplicar métodos científicos na resolução de problemas usando dados aleatórios
- Identifica os requisitos de dados para um determinado problema
- Identificar técnicas para obter os resultados desejados
- Fornecer valor para organizações que usam dados

---

**Ciência de Dados vs Mineração de Dados**

A Mineração de Dados é uma atividade que faz parte de um processo mais amplo de Descoberta de Conhecimento em Bancos de Dados (KDD), enquanto a Ciência de Dados é um campo de estudo como a Matemática Aplicada ou a Ciência da Computação.
Muitas vezes, a Ciência de Dados é considerada em um sentido amplo, enquanto a Mineração de Dados é considerada um nicho.

Algumas atividades na Mineração de Dados, como análise estatística, gravação de fluxos de dados e reconhecimento de padrões, podem cruzar com a Ciência de Dados. Portanto, Mineração de Dados se torna um subconjunto da Ciência de Dados.

O Aprendizado de Máquina na Mineração de Dados é mais usado no reconhecimento de padrões, enquanto na Ciência de Dados ele tem um uso mais geral.

**Nota**

*A Ciência de Dados e a Mineração de Dados não devem ser confundidas com Análise de Big Data e é possível ter "Miners" e "Scientists" trabalhando em grandes conjuntos de dados.*

---

**Ciência de Dados vs Aprendizagem de Máquina**

Abaixo está a diferença entre Ciência de Dados e Aprendizagem de Máquina:

**Componentes** - Os sistemas da Ciência de Dados cobrem todo o ciclo de vida dos dados e normalmente possuem componentes para cobrir os seguintes itens:

- Coleta e criação de perfil de dados -  pipelines ETL (Extract Transform Load) e criação de perfil
- Computação distribuída - Distribuição e processamento de dados horizontalmente escaláveis
- Automatização de inteligência - Modelos automatizados de ML para respostas online (previsão, recomendações) e detecção de fraudes.
- Visualização de dados - Explore visualmente os dados para obter uma melhor intuição dos dados. A parte integral da modelagem ML.
- Painéis e BI - Painéis predefinidos com recursos de fatia e dados para as partes interessadas de nível superior.
- Engenharia de dados - Garantir que os dados quentes e frios estejam sempre acessíveis. Cobre backup de dados, segurança, recuperação de desastres
- Implantação no modo de produção - Migre o sistema para produção com práticas padrão do setor.
- Decisões automatizadas - Isso inclui a execução de lógica de negócios em cima de dados ou um modelo matemático complexo treinado usando qualquer algoritmo ML.

A modelagem da Aprendizagem de Máquina começa com os dados existentes e os componentes típicos são os seguintes:

**Entenda o problema** - Certifique-se de maneira eficiente para resolver o problema é ML. Note que nem todos os problemas podem ser resolvidos usando o ML.

**Explorar Dados** - Para obter uma intuição de recursos a serem usados ​​no modelo ML. Isso pode precisar de mais de uma iteração. A visualização de dados desempenha um papel crítico aqui.

**Prepare dados** - Esta é uma etapa importante com alto impacto na precisão do modelo ML. Ele lida com questões de dados como o que fazer com a falta de dados para um recurso? Substitua com valor fictício como zero, ou média de outros valores ou elimine o recurso do modelo. Os recursos de dimensionamento, que garantem que os valores de todos os recursos estejam no mesmo intervalo, são críticos para muitos modelos ML. Muitas outras técnicas, como a geração de recursos polinomiais, também são usadas aqui para derivar novos recursos.

**Selecione um modelo e treine** - O modelo é selecionado com base em um tipo de problema (Previsão ou classificação etc.) e no tipo de conjunto de recursos (alguns algoritmos funcionam com um pequeno número de instâncias com um grande número de recursos e outros em outros casos).

**Medida de desempenho** - Na Ciência de Dados, as medidas de desempenho não são padronizadas, ela será alterada caso a caso. Tipicamente, será uma indicação de Data Timeliness, Data Quality, Querying Capability, Limites de simultaneidade no acesso aos dados, Capacidade de visualização interativa, etc.

---

**Ciência de Dados vs Inteligência Artificial**

Tanto a Ciência de Dados quanto a Inteligência Artificial são escolhas populares no mercado; Vamos discutir algumas das principais diferenças entre Ciência de Dados e Inteligência Artificial:

- A Ciência de Dados é a coleção e curadoria de dados em massa para análise, enquanto a Inteligência Artificial está implementando esses dados na Máquina para entender esses dados.
- Ciência de Dados é uma coleção de habilidades, como técnica estatística, enquanto técnica de algoritmo de inteligência artificial.
- A ciência dos dados usa o aprendizado estatístico, enquanto a inteligência artificial é de aprendizado de máquina.
- A Ciência de Dados observa um padrão nos dados para a tomada de decisão, enquanto os AIs buscam um relatório inteligente para decisão.
- A ciência de dados faz parte de um loop do ciclo de percepção e planejamento da IA ​​com ação
- Em Ciência de Dados, o processamento é de nível médio para manipulação de dados, enquanto o processamento de alta ordem de dados científicos para manipulação de AIs.
- Na ciência de dados, a representação gráfica está envolvida, enquanto no algoritmo de inteligência artificial e na representação do nó da rede
- Técnica de inteligência artificial envolve para processo de controle robótico enquanto ciência de dados em mineração de dados e manipulação.

---

**Ciência de Dados vs Big Data**

Abaixo estão algumas das principais diferenças entre os conceitos de big data e data science:

- As organizações precisam de big data para melhorar a eficiência, entender novos mercados e aumentar a competitividade, enquanto a ciência de dados fornece os métodos ou mecanismos para entender e utilizar o potencial do big data de maneira oportuna.
- Atualmente, para as organizações, não há limite para a quantidade de dados valiosos que podem ser coletados, mas para usar todos esses dados para extrair informações significativas para decisões organizacionais, a ciência de dados é necessária.
- Big data é caracterizado por sua variedade e volume de velocidades (popularmente conhecidos como 3Vs), enquanto a data science fornece os métodos ou técnicas para analisar dados caracterizados por 3Vs.
- Big data fornece o potencial para desempenho. No entanto, desenterrar informações de insight de big data para utilizar seu potencial para melhorar o desempenho é um desafio significativo. A ciência de dados usa abordagens teóricas e experimentais além do raciocínio dedutivo e indutivo. Assume a responsabilidade de descobrir todas as informações perspicazes ocultas de uma malha complexa de dados não estruturados, dando suporte às organizações a perceberem o potencial do Big Data.
- A análise de big data realiza a mineração de informações úteis a partir de grandes volumes de conjuntos de dados. Ao contrário da análise, a ciência de dados faz uso de algoritmos de aprendizado de máquina e métodos estatísticos para treinar o computador a aprender sem muita programação para fazer previsões a partir de dados grandes. Portanto, a ciência de dados não deve ser confundida com a análise de big data.
- O Big Data está mais relacionado à tecnologia ( Hadoop , Java , Hive , etc.), computação distribuída e ferramentas e software de análise. Isso se opõe à ciência de dados que se concentra em estratégias para decisões de negócios, disseminação de dados usando matemática, estatística e estruturas de dados e métodos mencionados anteriormente.

Das diferenças acima entre big data e ciência de dados, pode-se notar que a ciência de dados está incluída no conceito de big data. A ciência de dados desempenha um papel importante em muitas áreas de aplicação. A ciência de dados trabalha com big data para obter insights úteis por meio de análise preditiva, na qual os resultados são usados ​​para tomar decisões inteligentes. Portanto, a ciência de dados é incluída em big data, e não o contrário.

> Referências:
>
> [What is Data Science?](https://www.thinkful.com/blog/what-is-data-science/)
>
> [Comparisons Between Data Science vs Statistics](https://www.educba.com/data-science-vs-statistics/)
>
> [Useful Difference Between Data Science vs Machine Learning](https://www.educba.com/data-science-vs-machine-learning/)
>
> [Data Science Vs Data Engineering – Which One Is More Useful](https://www.educba.com/data-science-vs-data-engineering/)
>
> [Difference Between Data Science Vs Data Mining](https://www.educba.com/data-science-vs-data-mining/)
>
> [Data Science vs Artificial> Intelligence](https://www.educba.com/data-science-vs-artificial-intelligence/)
>
> [Big Data vs Data Science – How Are They Different> ?](https://www.educba.com/big-data-vs-data-science/)